# Respond to a post request

Tags: c++, sockets, post

I send a post request

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:5002",
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  data: "username=" +  "heyyyys",
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
    return response;        
  }
});
```

I have successfully accept a request

```
int result = recv(server, buffer, bufSize, 0);
cout << buffer << endl;
```

Here buffer:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5002
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 16
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/osrm/main.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

username=heyyyys
```

I'm trying to answer

```
response << "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
<< "HOST: localhost:5002\r\n"
<< "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
<< "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
<< "Accept: */*\r\n"
<< "Content-Length: 4\r\n"
<< "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
<< "resp";
send(server, response.str().c_str(), response.str().length(), 0);
```

But it is impossible to answer.
Tell me what my mistake.

Comment: you are sending a post request back, not a result...  fire up fiddler or chrome/ie dev tools and look at a few actual post requests and responses and your problem should be quite apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks casey, 
I saw examples of post requests in chrome dev tools and on the basis of such a response was generated:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 10 Oct 2010 23:26:07 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 11
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

hello world!
```